# I am trying to make an enemy follow my player and it has this error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im making a simple game right now where the enemy follows the player and I was watching tutorials how to do it and I made sure I hade code correct. This is the code.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour{
    public Transform player;
    public float moveSpeed = 3f;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private Vector2 movement;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start(){
        rb = this.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update(){
        Vector3 direction = player.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        rb.rotation = angle;
        direction.Normalize();
        movement = direction;
    }
    private void FixedUpdate() {
        moveCharacter(movement);
    }
    void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction){
        rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (direction * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime));
    }   
}
```

And this is the error - Operator '+' is ambiguous on operands of type 'Vector3' and 'Vector2'

Comment: change it to `void moveCharacter(Vector3 direction){`

Comment: your Enemy class field `private Vector2 movement` should probably be of `Vector3` instead, as well as the method `void moveCharacter(Vector2 direction)`, where direction should be of `Vector3`